# Cassandra Timestamp Type Column Conversion

Tags: c#, cassandra, thrift

I'll be very impressed if someone can solve my problem.

I am using the Cassandra Thrift API via C#. I have a "timestamp" type column in Cassandra, which is supposed to be seconds since the Unix epoch expressed as an 8-byte long.

To convert, I do this:

```
BitConverter.GetBytes(ToUnixTimestamp(columnValue)));
```

where:

```
protected static long ToUnixTimestamp(DateTime dateTime)
{
    return Convert.ToInt64((dateTime - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).ToLocalTime()).TotalSeconds);
}
```

When I check my value in the CLI, I see:

```
=> (column=created, value=225330207-01-15 03:30:53-0500, timestamp=1356568301)
```

Cassandra is not interpreting the value I insert correctly. The year **225330207** is not what I was inserting. Why is this happening and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to store and retrieve values from the "timestamp" type column as **milliseconds** since the Unix epoch, not seconds.

http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql/CQL.html#usingdates